# Double integral with integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

This is for an online web assignment with multiple choice.

$ \int_1^2 \int_0^1 xye^{(x^{2}+1)y} $

I solved the inner integral with respect to y:

$\int_0^1 xye^{(x^{2}+1)y} $ =  $\frac{e^{x^{2}+1}x^{3}+x}{(x^{2}+1)^{2}}$

I'm not sure how to integrate the result with respect to x. This seems like a rather complicated integral for an online exercise. Is there an easier way to solve this integral?

Comment: Hint: notice that at the exponent you have $ y(x^2 + 1)$, and outside the exponential you have $ xy $...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an extremely difficult function to integrate with respect to $x$. Try reversing the order of integration first: The result will be that you're integrating

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \int_1^2 xy e^{(x^2 + 1) y} dx dy &= \int_0^1 xy \frac{e^{(x^2 + 1) y}}{2xy} \Big|_{x = 1}^{x = 2} dy
\end{align*}

which, upon evaluation, will have a sum of pure exponentials in $y$